# Select layer by attribute using SQL statement LEN() in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql, select-by-attribute

I want to query the length of a string column and thought to use:

```
LEN([ColumnName]) > 5
```

However, that doesn't work at all. I'm querying a table in a fGDB in ArcMap 10.1, hence the notation of [ColumnName].

Can someone help me?

The error message I'm getting from ArcGIS is that I'm using an invalid SQL statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To calculate the length in characters of a string expression use `CHAR_LENGTH(string_exp)`

Field name delimiters for file geodatabase is double quotes (not square brackets).

So this should work:

```
CHAR_LENGTH(“ColumnName“) > 5
```

Here is a [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/).

Answer (score 1):

What if you add a new field to your table called, for example, "str_length" and then populate the field with the length of the value of the field you want?

```
str_length = len(columnname)
```

Then do your selection on the new calculated field.